# Trying to use methods on values within get and set accessors gives a .Net framework error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, poco

I am trying to use some methods within set/get accessors on properties of classes generated by entity framework. Purpose is to encrypt the field before saving to DB and Decrypt the fields before reading from DB.I am doing it at the POCO class level so that the encryption-decryption happens while interacting with DB itself and I dont have to scriible through a lot of code. Is the POCO class the best interface to do that? 
Code builds successfully, but I get a .Net Framework error when I execute it and the visual studio process is killed eventually.

I am not sure, I might be making some very basic error, but haven't been able to get down to it. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated !

```
[Table("Users")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public Int32 UserID { set; get; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public String UserName  // This is where I am using encryption decryption methods
    { 
        set
        {
            this.UserName = NewEncryptionMethod(value);
        }

        get
        {
            return NewDecryptionMethod(this.UserName);
        } 
    }

    [Required]
    public Int32 CustID { set; get; }
```

Comment: You have to use a backing field to store value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that it's failing right now is because you're running into an infinite amount of calling the `get` part of `UserName` since you're trying to grab the value by trying to grab the value and decrypting it. This will cause an overflow error eventually.

Your solution to this is to leave the records in the database as they are, bring them over, and then use a ViewModel class that will contain the decrypted data. When you want to go back to the database, simply encrypt the value in the ViewModel and push that value to the database.

Answer (score 1):

I don't say that the way you are doing the work is good , first thing i can say is that you have infinite recursive call.

Solution:

```
private string _username;

[Required]
[MaxLength(50)]
public String UserName  // This is where I am using encryption decryption methods
{ 
    set
    {
        _username = NewEncryptionMethod(value);
    }
    get
    {
       //you have to deal with a null username here is a bad but quick solution
       _username = _username ?? string.Empty;
        return NewDecryptionMethod(_username);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep in UserName raw, insecure data. But make this property internal.

```
// map me
internal string UserName { get; set; }
```

And secure it using another property but public:

```
// don't map me
public string SecureUserName
{
    get { return Encrypt(UserName);
    set { UserName = Encrypt(value); }
}
```

Another way is to use a separate class for this purpose, say `SecureUser` or `UserViewModel`:

```
public class SecureUser
{
    private readonly User _user;

    public SecureUser(User user)
    {
        _user = user;
    }

    public string UserName
    {
        get { return Encrypt(_user.UserName);
        set { _user.UserNAme = Decrypt(value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @abatishchev , The earlier soln of keeping internal prop Username did not work, but I am going to give a try making a class or using ViewModel

Comment: @Shweta: hi, what didn't work? Note that I omitted the mapping details in the code in my question. However I'd go with way #2, this is the proper separation of concerns.

Comment: thanks again! I am looking fwd to approach#2. Although, my point is also to understand whether properties in POCO class is the right place for encryption/Decryption interaction with DB?

Comment: @ShwetaSaxena: I think it should be a separate layer to achieve that. EF maps property pretty straight forward (however you can have different names). So what you have in db column reader - you have in property setter. But you can hide this in your data access layer and make available to a higher layer only modified entities (in your particular case - encrypted).

Comment: @ShwetaSaxena: Say you have User and UserViewModel. Then you have a constructor for UserViewModel accepting User, i.e. `new UserViewModel(User user)`. You keep it in Models.dll.

Comment: Then you have your Data Access Layer (Dal.dll) referencing this Models.dll. You have something like a Repository or Unit of Work accepting that UserViewModel to save.

Comment: You can expose underlying user as a read-only property `public User { get; private set; }` or static method like `public static User FromViewModel(UserViewModel userViewModel)`

Comment: @ShwetaSaxena: Great! Pleas find some time to accept my answer (using green tick to the left).

Comment: @ShwetaSaxena: The best way is to ask a new question, and just give me a link to it.